# Show the gold badge when close as duplicate in mobile app

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, ios-app

It's strange how the mobile app differs from the website itself. I'm requesting to **show** the *gold badge of the user*, who closes the question as an exact duplicate, in the iOS app (just like in the website).

As you can see, in the iOS app view, all you can see is the name of the user who closes it. While in the webview, the name is clickable, and more importantly, there's the gold badge beside the name, which is what enables the user to close as duplicate in the first place.

Side question: why does the iOS app shows "Closed as duplicate" while the web shows "Marked as duplicate"? Shouldn't they be the same?

iOS mobile app view:
[image]

iOS Safari web view:
[image]

Comment: I don't have/use/or really want the mobile app, but the more inconsistencies I see being posted about on meta have been tempering my desire *against* using it.... (that said, I generally despise mobile versions of websites, as I have a tablet which has a large enough screen to be recognized as not-a-mobile-device when in landscape mode, so mobile layouts are often wasted on me).

Comment: I have a flip-phone. I'm sure we could fit something in its 42 pixels.